# Repetition when joining two table sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am displaying records from two table but i am having repetition.

**TABLE CHAPTER**

`chapterID,ID,cTitle,cDescription`

**TABLE PAGE**

```
pageId,chapterID,pageName,Icon
```

Current output i am getting:
[image]

The desired output:

[image]

```
    <?php 
        $con=mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '') or die ( 'could not connect to db:'. mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db( 'database') or die( 'No db found'); 
        $count = 1; 
        $query = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT chapter.cTitle,chapter.cDescription,page.pageName,page.pageIcon FROM chapter INNER JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID = page.chapterID") or die( 'Query failed'); 
        while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
            echo $result[ 'cTitle']; echo $result[ 'cDescription']; 
            echo $result[ 'pageName']; $count +=1; 
        } 
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to repeat `chapter Title` and `description` for all the `pages` then this is not a Job for `SQL`

Comment: @VR46 i want to repeat `chapter Title` and `description` but the next chapter that follows that is `chapter 2`

with the code i ahve provided  am having the following output
`chapter 1 - page 1`
`chapter 1 - page 2` and so on

Comment: Still not clear. Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: As @VR46 mentioned, it is not the job of sql, you will require to first get the distinct list of CHAPTER id, title and description and using this resultset id field will have to execute another sql which will give you chapter's pages.

Comment: @VR46 please see the edited version

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela please see the edit

Comment: Please dont do this in SQL

Comment: So based on @VR46 comment, for Left Hand Side you will write one query to get list of chapter's id, title and description. Loop through this result set to get list of pages chapter wise and generate Right Hand side view.

Comment: @Neha You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a comma delimited string of pages **but this should be handled on page level**.

Comment: if its not appropriate to do so in sql - any alternative ?

Comment: You should be changing your PHP code, not your SQL code.  Scan through your results (you'll need to add `ORDER BY` for stability), and only output chapter title/description if the previous one was different.  You may not need the `DISTINCT`.  Alternatively, PDO may be able to present this sort of view for you.

Comment: can you show table strunctures?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
SELECT DISTINCT ....
```

try using

```
SELECT ....
GROUP BY chapter.cTitle,chapter.cDescription;
```

Have you maintained **foreign key** relationship among the two tables ?

Comment: yes foreign key maintained. i tried 
` SELECT DISTINCT chapter.cTitle,chapter.cDescription,.....`
but still same

Comment: If you list all columns in the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY`, the result returned is equivalent to the output of `DISTINCT` (and probably use the same underlying function).  If you leave out columns, you get 'random' results for columns not in aggregate functions (in MySQL - pretty much everything else throws an error due to the danger); which wouldn't help anyways because they still need all the results from the non-grouped columns, not any of them.